# How to do endless scrolling in recyclerview, in both left and right directions?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, endlessscroll

I have an endless recycler view which I populate with data as scrolling is done. When I scroll right, it works perfectly. Problem is I can't figure out how to scroll left endlessly. If I am able to scroll, only then will I be able to populate the views with data. I have checked many similar queries on stackoverflow but all of them address endless scrolling only in right side direction or downward in the case of vertical recyclerview.
For example, [How to implement load more recyclerview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889955/how-to-implement-load-more-recyclerview-in-android).
I want load more to get triggered while scrolling in either direction.

Comment: show code you have implemented so far

Comment: @Kavya, You can test this Library https://github.com/Malinskiy/SuperRecyclerView

Comment: and customize it accordingly

Comment: refere this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242958/infinite-scroll-of-finite-items/47286202#47286202

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create horizontal RecyclerView from left to right add. It's default direction.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

If you want to change the default from right to left use

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

You **must** choose the direction as you can't set scrolling to both sides . New items will be loaded to left or to right according to what you choose